# Socket read URL

Tags: c++, boost-asio

i want, to get the url content (http://127.0.0.1:1337/test/test), so in this case "/test/test", how i can do that?

```
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void ts3plugin_initWebsocket() {
    try
    {
        auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1");
        auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi("1337"));
        boost::asio::io_context ioc{ 1 };
        tcp::acceptor acceptor{ ioc, {address, port} };
        while (true) {
            tcp::socket socket{ ioc };
            acceptor.accept(socket);
            

            ts3Functions.logMessage("Connected", LogLevel_INFO, "Plugin", 1);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        char msg[512];
        snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "Error: %s", e.what());
        ts3Functions.logMessage(msg, LogLevel_INFO, "Plugin", 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with Asio, and everything with HTTP. You want to make a GET request, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET

Going by the naming you might also want to upgrade to Websocket protocol over HTTP. Instead of figuring out how to do all that, perhaps just go by one of the Beast examples:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html